# Modify a matrix by summing specific rows into a new row

Tags: r, if-statement, aggregate

I have a large data matrix of 2289 rows. A sample picture is attached. The matrix is called speciesTraps. All column values are numeric. I need to aggregate any rows to the previous row if `speciesTraps[,1]` is equal to zero. After reading other people's question and answers, I was thinking of creating a loop to do this with the following statement:

```
for (i in 1: nrow(subsetTrapsplusid)) {
  row <- subsetTrapplusid[i, ]
  if (subsetTrapsplusid[[1]] = 0) {
    print(aggregate(subsetTrapsplusid[row, ], subsetTrapsplusid[(row - 1), ], sum))
  } else {
    (print(subsetTrapsplusid[i, ]))
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have a suggestion.

Screenshot of datamatrix:

[image: screenshot of datamatrix]

Comment: Please add the language as tag.

Comment: english... Is that what you mean Mika?

Comment: No, the programming language you are using. People who are interested in the language you are using (R?) won't see this question otherwise.

Comment: Oh yes I was coding in R studio